# fast lookup in python

Tags: python, lookup

I have entries (~88 millions in all) in the following format:

```
userid  age test    value
111 33  SODIUM  140
111 34  POTASSIUM   4.1
333 65.4    CHLORIDE    107
444 24  BICARBONATE 24
```

I need to create a fast lookup for the `value` in last column, given the first three items (ie. `userid`, `age`, `test`).

What is the best way to repeatedly lookup into this data? One that I am thinking of is to create a dictionary in which the `keys` are the tuple (`userid`, `age`, `test`) and values are `value`. In the past I used similar method and this method was very slow on much smaller data.

Comment: you use a database. do NOT load 88 million records into memory in python. that's insane/ludicrous.

Comment: LOL... Perhaps http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

Comment: Dictionaries are based on hash tables, which is about as fast as Python can get. If that was too slow for you, you need a different approach. As @MarcB says, a database is more appropriate for that volume of data but it's going to be even slower.

Comment: @Vini `str.split`? why?

Comment: Well, I was going to refer to it as a string with tab separators pushed into an array until I saw 88 million...

Answer (score 5):

You should use a database, you have too much entries. It is the job of database to do lookup and indexes over so much data.

Comment: In >5 years someone will read this answer and say: "A database? For under 100 million records? Ridiculous." :)

Comment: If things like `LINQ` in `C#` are integrated into other languages to sift and filter through our collections... then yes this may become outdated in the future... Though it would still resemble more or less to the `SQL` language.

Comment: It is 5 years now since he asked this question. I think it is ridculous not to use a database.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about memory usage: Stick in in a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Note that the above is likely to use up all your memory, unless you have a *lot* of memory. Do it bit by bit and see how much you can load. A quick test indicates you need at least 16GB of internal memory.

Otherwise: Use a database. [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is included, PostgreSQL is good for professional use, but there are loads and loads of alternatives, including NoSQL ones as Redis etc, which may be good here.

Answer (score 0):

Wo, wo, wo there. 88 million? As in, 88,000,000?

You have to use a database. Try `redis` for a very lightweight, fast-lookup alternative. You can use the first three values for key.

`redis` will even give you some nifty operations on the data, you may save yourself the roundtrip.

Comment: Euh no, you mistake millions with billions. It makes 88.000.000 ( only :-) )

Comment: Haha! I did, indeed! Well use a `dict` then :P